# Eclipse - How to add a new MariaDB connection

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jdbc, database-connection, mariadb

How can I add a new MariaDB connection to eclipse?

I am using the Data Source Explorer view, however when I try to create a new database connection there are connections for MySQL, Oracle, Informix... but no for MariaDB.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 15):

If you need to create a database connection for MariaDB, you choose "Generic JDBC" and click Next.

In next window click on "new driver definition" button then choose "Generic JDBC Driver" from "Available driver templates"

In "JAR List", add the Maria connector.  You can get it from (https://downloads.mariadb.com/enterprise/152y-977s/connectors/java/connector-java-1.4.6/mariadb-java-client-1.4.6.jar). I used "mariadb-java-client-1.4.6.jar"

In "Properties", enter the following data

```
Connection URL: jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/database_name
Database Name: database_name
Driver Class: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
```

You can set User ID to empty and validate username and password of your database.
Test if it connects.

Comment: To get the latest MariaDB connector, it's better to go here: https://downloads.mariadb.com/Connectors/java/latest/