# Eclipse - MariaDB JDBC onnection issue (bug or I messed up something?)

Tags: eclipse, jdbc, mariadb

I started learning Java EE, and I decided to develop my small application in simulated "real world production" environment:

I decoupled the development and deployment environment into a laptop (with Eclipse IDE) and a server (Raspberry Pi with Tomcat/TomEE and MariaDB).
With this environment I can learn not only EE development but the deployment phase, too.

### The problem

After installation of MariaDB I realized that the MariaDB's JDBC connector doesn't work properly. I successfully made a connection in Eclipse via Generic JDBC [(I used MariaDB's default connector)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dZCw.png). Pinging the server was also [successful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMi12.png), but every query returned [void results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDBRW.png).

I tried the following queries:

- `show tables in dbName;`
- `select * from tableName;`
- `show databases;`

When I tried to make entities from tables in a new JPA project, Eclipse didn't offered any tables.

Can somebody please help me to make a complete working connection to MariaDB.

### What did I try (until this moment, without result)?

- Updated the Raspbian system by apt-get update, moreover I did the same after installing MariaDB.
- Tried to install MySql 5.6 with apt-get and dpkg, but the armhf version is not available on Raspbian Stretch
- In Eclipse's Preferences/Data Management/Connectivity/Driver Definitions I tried to install MySql driver instead Generic JDBC
- In properties (in Edit Driver Definition) tried the following Connection URL-s:

  - `jdbc:mysql://hostName:port/`
  - `jdbc:mariadb://hostName:port/`
  - `jdbc:mysql://hostName:port/dbName`
  - `jdbc:mariadb://hostName:port/dbName`
  - `jdbc:mysql://hostName:port/dbName?user=userName&password=password`
  - `jdbc:mariadb://hostName:port/dbName?user=userName&password=password`
- Tried older version of JDBC connectors, too (mariadb-java-client-2.1.0.jar), without good result.
- I installed MySQL on local machine, I could connect it in Eclipse successfully.
- I could successfully connect, create, insert, alter tables in MariaDB from locally installed [MySqlWorkbench.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5idtJ.png)
- I installed MariaDB on local machine. Despite the connection ping was successful in Eclipse, the void query result was the same as the remote MariaDB connection.
- I installed NetBeans to check whether I can connect MariaDB with it's driver. The result was SUCCESS [(screenshot is attached)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsAck.png)
- One more weird thing: in Data Source Explorer the tree structure is different between MySQL and MariaDB [(see the screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVAZv.png)

### The environment

Server:

- Raspbian Stretch (Debian 9.1)
- Java: openJKD 1.8.0_141, OpenJDK Runtime Environment build 1.8.0_141-8u141-b15-1~deb9ul-b15, OpenJDK Zero VM build 25.141-b15-1~deb9ul-b15
- MariaDB Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.23-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnueabihf (armv71)

Local machine:

- Windows 10 Pro 64bit, version: 1703, build: 15063.674 (Hungarian language local)

  - MySqlWorkbench 6.3CE, 6.3.9 build 10690321 CE(64 bits)
  - Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3), Build id: 20170314-1500
  - NetBeans IDE 8.2, Build 201705191307
  - Java: JDK 1.8.0_151 (x86_64 architecture)
  - JDBC: mariadb-java-client-2.1.2.jar (This worked successfully with NetBeans)

To summarize, in Eclipse I can make a connection to MariaDB via Generic JDBC, the ping is successful, but I cannot get any result from queries (and cannot generate entities from tables).

Comment: did you use the connector jar mentioned here as well as follow the suggested connector params? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36557936/eclipse-how-to-add-a-new-mariadb-connection

Comment: FWIW, I just got MariaDB Connector/J 2.1.2 working in Eclipse's Data Source Explorer by "cheating": I created a new connection using the "MySQL" profile type and then created a new Driver Definition named "MariaDB JDBC 2.1.2" that pointed to mariadb-java-client-2.1.2.jar. (Previously I had tried creating a connection using the "Generic JDBC" profile type and I saw the same strange behaviour that you did, specifically in the tree view of the Data Source Explorer.)

Comment: Hi Syed, thank you for your fast answer. I tried it. With MariaDB JDBC 1.4, 1.5 and 1.6. I can get results in SQL Scrapbook, but I still cannot generate Entities from tables. Eclipse's Data Source Explorer still don't display tables :(

Comment: Gord, thank you. I tried the same, but when I created the new connection in Data Source Explorer using MySQL profile,  I could only select from 4 options: MySQL 4.0, 4.1, 5.0 or 5.1.at the new Driver Definition part. Could you please be more specific how and which option did you choose exactly because I tried them all and I got connection errors: "Could not connect to sql.
Error creating SQL Model Connection connection to sql. (Error: com.mariadb.jdbc.Driver)
com.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
Error creating JDBC Connection connection to sql. (Error: com.mariadb.jdbc.Driver)
com.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:**
In Eclipse you don't have to use MariaDB's JDBC 2.1.2. connector. It is fully MySQL compatible just use MySQL JDBC 5.1 default (mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar). Now it works fine!